# APOの信号処理関数で更新された変数の値を取得できない。

Tags: c++, windows

以下のサイトを参考にAPOを作成しています。
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/audio-processing-object-architecture

APOはユーザーモードのDLLなので、APOとCOMクライアントの間でメモリを共有することが出来ると理解しています。
なので、私はdata_segプラグマを使う方法とCreateFileMapping関数を使う方法を試して、APOとCOMクライアントでメモリの共有ができるかを試してみました。
（上記リンクの図に記載されているApplication（COMクライアント）とMFXでメモリーを共有しようとしています）

結論としては、コンストラクタなど非リアルタイム処理で更新された値は取得出来たのですが、
リアルタイムに信号処理を実施するAPOProcess関数内で更新された値は取得することは出来ませんでした。

#### 質問

- なぜ信号処理関数で更新された値をCOMクライアントは取得出来ないのでしょうか？
- APOの信号処理関数で更新された値を取得する方法はありますか？

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: そもそも関連するコンポーネント間でメモリーを共有して並行処理するという発想が無いのかもしれませんよ。たまたま出来たとしてもずっと有効とは限らないのでは？ 紹介記事には共有メモリとかメモリマップドファイルに関連しそうな内容は無さそうです。記事の下の方にソフトウェアの構成や連携の図があるので、何処と何処の間で共有してるか追記すると助言や回答が得られるかもしれませんね。ちなみに日本語化記事があるようです。[オーディオ処理オブジェクトのアーキテクチャ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/audio-processing-object-architecture)

Comment: @kunif
コメントいただき、ありがとうございます。  
以下のページでAPOとCOMクライアントはデータの共有が出来ると回答があったので、そうかなと思っていました。  
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315852/can-apo-use-shared-memory.html  
  
ただ、ご指摘のように、そもそもAPOはデバドラの一部として動くものなので、メモリーを共有して動くという思想ではないのかもしれないですね。

Comment: 上記のリンクの回答をよくよく読んでみると、APOのカーネルモード部分では共有セグメントは意味が無いと記載されていますね。